# ¿Cómo se conjuga el verbo jugar en el presente de subjuntivo con el pronombre vos en el dialecto chileno?

Tags: subjuntivo, chile, voseo

Soy nicaragüense, pero me interesa el tema. Con lo que he visto sobre el dialecto chileno, mi suposición sería *que vos jugís*, pero no estoy seguro si esa respuesta es correcta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La forma voseante de los chilenos es ***juguís***, con una *s* final muy relajada, casi *juguí*.

Ten presente que casi no usamos el pronombre *vos* (se puede escuchar pero no es muy frecuente, y a veces suena un poco agresivo). Preferimos el pronombre *tú* (o ninguno), y la conjugación queda igual.

Ejemplos:

> Me avisai cuando juguí. (*Avísame cuando juegues*)
>
> No juguís mucho rato. (*No juegues mucho rato*)
>
> Ojalá que tú juguís de arquero. (*Ojalá que tú juegues de arquero*)

Comment: Y para aclarar el deletreo: se necesita la U para endurecer la G, porque sin la U, la G se oiría como J.

Comment: @aparente001 Sí, ustedes tienen razón. Como he dicho, soy nicaragüense, así que no sé cómo funciona en Chile. Pensaba que tal vez el deletreo no obedeciera las reglas del deletreo, pero ustedes me lo clarificaron. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @rodrigo de hecho, tanto la forma con S y como la sin S quedan registradas como terminaciones válidas (y todas las demás formas)